# C# and Excel automation Add-in problems

Tags: c#, excel, automation, add-in

I'm kind of new to c# and trying to create an automation add-in for excel and I followed the instructions given in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx)

This is working fine when I use numbers as parameters to the function called from a cell

```
 =MultiplyNTimes(3,7,8)
```

but when I use cell addresses

```
=MultiplyNTimes(A1,B2,C3)
```

excel doesn't recognize the function and it throws the #NAME error.

Debugging in VS, I can see that the function is not even called.

Comment: I forgot to say I'm using VS2010 and excel 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant, but try this:

```
=MultiplyNTimes(VALUE(A1),VALUE(B2),VALUE(C3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing, but the first thing I would try is to to change the function parameters for

```
public double MultiplyNTimes(double number1, double number2, double timesToMultiply)
```

to

```
public double MultiplyNTimes(Excel.Range number1, Excel.Range number2, Excel.Range timesToMultiply)
```

..to get it to accept worksheet cell addresses instead of numeric values.